# Pass command field from main report to crosstab formula in sub report?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I have a master detail report. The crosstab is included in detail section inside a subreport.

How to pass a command field from main report to cross tab formula field in sub report ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using Shared Formulas.

In your main report create a new Formula Field - it can be called whatever you like. Create a shared variable and assign it a value.

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
shared stringVar MAINREPORTVAR := {Table.ColumnName}
```

In your sub report, create a new Formula Field and enter the following:

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Shared StringVar MAINREPORTVAR;
MAINREPORTVAR
```

The variables names in both of the formulas must be the same.

This will display the value of the Formula field from your main report on your sub report.  You can then use this in your cross-tab.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Barry. I am able to pass the fields to the sub report. Only problem being is that crosstab formula fields use WhileReadingRecords , in which a shared variable cannot be declared.

Comment: @Damien - Hmm, maybe you could create another formula in the sub-report that points to the shared formula and then use that in your cross tab?